# Which researchers in electrical engineering do work related to DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, materials-design, materials-engineering, soft-question

I would like to gain knowledge about how DFT calculations can be specifically used in the subject of electrical engineering. **It would really help if people in the community can direct me towards scholars or professors or scientists who are actively working on it. I would really like to follow them.**

Comment: DFT only work for atomistic systems. IF you are interested in studying properties (optical, electronic, IR, RAMAN, etc.) it can useful.

Comment: @Camps Sir I meant what areas of Electrical engineering can DFT touch. Such as I was reading a paper titled "The performance limits of hexagonal boron nitride as an insulator for scaled CMOS devices based on two-dimensional materials". So I want to get acknowledged about such topics which might be energy conversion or energy storage. DFT used to solve questions of Electrical performance as a final goal. I want to follow such researchers in the community.

Comment: Did you ask this on EE.SE? You don't seem to have asked any questions there but I can't see deleted questions. I asked it [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64565066#64565066). I am curious though, if you can tell us why you are asking this question?

Comment: @NikeDattani I did not think of asking the ques on EE.SE. I am asking this ques basically because I am studying interdisciplinary topics from subjects of Electrical engineering, Material science, Physics and DFT computation. As I was researching I wanted to find some space where discussions on these topics happens together interlinking their concepts. For example I am doing some DFT calculations on semiconductors which can be used as solar cell materials, then if they can be synthesized - How does an electrical engineer approach it after analysing the properties found via DFT calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! You seem to be [asking many questions](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5) in one post, so I have narrowed it down to just one question. Hopefully now you will get an answer!

Comment: @NikeDattani Thank you so much.